# Why did they remove the support for VelocityEngineUtils from Spring Framework 5?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I tried to find dependencies of Spring Boot Velocity Starter for Spring-boot-starter:

- version 2.1.4.RELEASE.

However, I found that it was only listed till:

- version 1.4.7.RELEASE

What is the exact reason for removing this for Spring-boot 2+ versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was removed from Spring Framework, and thus Spring Boot.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10008

> Velocity support has been removed as of Spring Framework 5 and therefore our support as well (even deprecated in earlier version). As far as I can see there is no spring support in Velocity 2 so you may want to ask that to them first.

The relevant Spring Framework information,

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#removed-packages-classes-and-methods

> Dropped support: Portlet, Velocity, JasperReports, XMLBeans, JDO, Guava.
> Recommendation: Stay on Spring Framework 4.3.x for those if needed.

Why the decision was made I cannot answer, there is always various reasons for dropping support for other frameworks but perhaps it wasn't worth the maintenance burden on the framework.

Update,

There is now a Spring support module.

https://downloads.apache.org/velocity/engine/2.3/release-notes.html

> New spring-velocity-support module for Velocity Engine integration in Spring Framework.

For complete details please see.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VELOCITY-933

Comment: Velocity 2.3+ now includes a spring-velocity-support module.

Comment: @ClaudeBrisson I've updated the question, if theres any more documentation links or examples feel free to suggest an edit